# Observer with shared pointers

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

I am trying to write a simple observer class which registers and holds the object's shared pointer. Below is the code:

```
template <typename Ptr>
class S
{
  private:
    std::map<string,std::vector<shared_ptr<Ptr>> observers_;
  public:

  S()=default;

  void registerObserver(const string &event, shared_ptr<Ptr> observer)
  {
    observers_[event].push_back(observer);
  }

  void notify(const string&event) 
  {
    for (const auto& obs : observers_.at(event)) 
      obs->notify();
  }

};
```

This however fails compilation with this error:

```
Subject.h:51:50: error: template argument 2 is invalid
   51 |     std::map<string,std::vector<shared_ptr<Ptr>> observers_;
```

Can some one please help correct my declaration?

Comment: Presumably you want `std::string` and `std::shared_ptr` and not just `string`/`shared_ptr`.  But the concept of an observer that uses `shared_ptr` seems fishy to me; Maybe [`std::observer_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) or [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) would make more sense?

Comment: @0x5453 Sorry , i have clipped the "using namespace std" and other includes int he header. I understand this is poor design , i am just ruminating through the containers and building mock. Noted regarding the appropriate containers.

Comment: Please turn your code into a [mcve]

Comment: You seems missing a `>` in `std::map<string,std::vector<shared_ptr<Ptr>> observers_;`.

Comment: @songyuanyao embarrassing. Thanks! If you post it as an answer, i can accept this.

Comment: It appears you are trying to recreate [Boost Signals2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/signals2.html), which bears some semblance to C#/.NET event facilities.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to write a simple observer class which registers and holds the object's shared pointer.

Then you want to use [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr), which are specifically designed for this:

> std::weak_ptr models temporary ownership: when an object needs to be accessed only if it exists, and it may be deleted at any time by someone else, std::weak_ptr is used to track the object

Comment: I agree with your reasoning, but would this change fix the error in the question?

Comment: That's probably due to the typo `shared_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`.  This is more import, change over to `std::weak_ptr` and then sort out any compilation errors.